# How to parse through an NSMutable Array and add up the values

Tags: xcode, ios5, for-loop, nsmutablearray, sum

Im having problems trying to add (sum) up all the values in a NSMutable Array:  The ProfileItems contains data from a Core Data Entity, and is populated with the correct data.  I'm just having problems parsing through the NSMutableArray and adding up the profileItems.songLength data.

Thanks in advance

```
   ProfileItems *profileItems = [profileItemsNSMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Renumber the rows
    int numberOfRows = [profileItemsNSMArray count];
    NSLog(@"numberofRows: %d", numberOfRows);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) 
    {
        int sumOfSongs = sumOfSongs + [[profileItems.songLength] objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"length: %@",sumOfSongs);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fast enumeration, it will work much faster and requires much less code.

```
int sumOfSongs = 0;

for (ProfileItems *item in profileItemsNSMArray) {
   sumOfSongs = sumOfSongs + [item.songlength intValue]; // use intValue to force type to int
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  I just had to touch up the code, but works perfectly.  The only thing missing was the '*" in front of the item.                 for (ProfileItems *item in profileItemsNSMArray) {

Comment: Perfect. I updated my code in case anyone else comes across this answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `intValue` function on `NSMutableArray` object and use `%d` for printing integer.

```
ProfileItems *profileItems = [profileItemsNSMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Renumber the rows
    int numberOfRows = [profileItemsNSMArray count];
    NSLog(@"numberofRows: %d", numberOfRows);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) 
    {
        int sumOfSongs = sumOfSongs + [[[profileItems.songLength] objectAtIndex:i]intValue]; // use intValue

        NSLog(@"length: %d",sumOfSongs); //use %d for printing integer value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the objects in the NSMutableArray:

```
ProfileItems *profileItems = (ProfileItems*)[profileItemsNSMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

int numberOfRows = [profileItemsNSMArray count];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) 
{
    int sumOfSongs += [[profileItems.songLength] objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"length: %@",sumOfSongs);
}
```